# View content of android screen from linux PC

Tags: screen, miracast

Is it possible to view content of Android screen from PC running Linux over LAN?
VNC should works here, but I'm looking for something more real-time, so that video content can be viewed smoothly from linux PC.

I found an [miracast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) protocol which can possibly fits into my scenaro, but it requires wireless connection from both ends, where in my deployment, android device (TV box) is connected via LAN.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is: real-time video encoding requires quite a fast CPU and currently I have not seen a working screen mirroring app apart from the original Android *Cast Screen* option. One idea might be using a mini-USB to HDMI cable.

Answer (score 2):

[Scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) is your best option. There is a CLI & GUI version.

Comment: Agreed. Scrcpy is nice. Frame rate can be improved (I found videos choppy) but it works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but I think [AndroidScreencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) does what you want.

Comment: According to provided link,  it has slow refresh rate (about 4-5 fps),  so not an option.Nevertheless, interesting project, thanks.